# Jenkins volume permissions with matching userIDs

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to run a Jenkins Docker container and am getting Wrong volume permissions.
Looking around I can see that most people say that it is down to host folder ownership however my container has matching IDs so I cannot work out what is going on.

```
centos@ip-10-189-173-122 ~]$ docker run -ti jenkins/jenkins /bin/bash
jenkins@65ae3a6726f8:/$ id
uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins)
jenkins@beb6a3a225da:/$ ls -nl /var/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2    0    0  6 Jun 26 12:03 backups
drwxr-xr-x. 1    0    0 22 Sep  5 01:21 cache
drwxr-xr-x. 3 1000 1000 78 Oct  3 14:49 jenkins_home
jenkins@65ae3a6726f8:/$ exit
exit
[centos@ip-10-189-173-122 ~]$ id
uid=1000(centos) gid=1000(centos) groups=1000(centos),4(adm),10(wheel),190(systemd-journal),1001(docker) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[centos@ip-10-189-173-122 ~]$ ll -n /home/centos/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 1000 1000 6 Oct  3 14:45 JENKINS
[centos@ip-10-189-173-122 ~]$ docker run -ti -v /home/centos/JENKINS:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins /bin/bash
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
```

Adding the --privileged flag makes this work and writes as the correct user :/

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely caused by SELinux. Change how you are mounting the volume by adding a `:z` or `:Z` to the end depending on whether other containers will share this same volume:

```
docker run -ti -v /home/centos/JENKINS:/var/jenkins_home:z \
  jenkins/jenkins /bin/bash
```

Documentation is a little thin on this setting. For more details, you can review https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be me using an old version of Docker, upgrading to the newer docker-ce resolves the issue. Not sure why though....